# Change, remove Login block title and local-tasks tabs

Tags: forms, blocks

I have altered login form, removed fields description like this (mytheme.theme):

```
function mytheme_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if (isset($form['name']) && $form['name']['#type'] == 'textfield') {
    unset($form['name']['#title'], $form['name']['#description']);
  }

  if (isset($form['pass']) && $form['name']['#type'] == 'textfield') {
    unset($form['pass']['#title'], $form['pass']['#description']);
  }

}
```

I want to go further and , remove Login block title and local-tasks (Login, Register, Reset password). How to do this? I could just CSS display none it, but thats sounds not very natural...

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with the hook_form_alter().

```
function your_custom_module_name_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
switch ($form_id) {
case 'user_register_form':
// print the $form and you can see the entire structure of the login form. 
//You can then unset or overwrite the elements.
break;
case 'user_login_block':
....
break;
case 'user_login':
....
break;
}
}
```